# Is chaining replaceFirst() calls inefficient for a chain of 51 calls?

Tags: java, string, replace

I'm working on some template based code that fills in placeholders by  chaining calls to String.replaceFirst() After collecting the data to replace placeholders this line builds the completed form.

```
String completedForm = template.replaceFirst("account_number",account_number).template.replaceFirst("customer_id",customer_id)... 49 more in the  chain
```

I'm wondering if this approach is unecessarily  costly because it creates 51 String objects in the  course of building  the completedForm.

Is this the best way from an efficiency point of view?

Comment: And what is `template` here? Your current code doesn't seem like it will compile at all. In any event, yes, a new `String` object will be created for the result of each substitution. What is more, given your initial input, this looks like a prime example of an XY problem.

Comment: Thanks for the  thoughtfull comments.  I guess I should have indicated what I thought a substitute for the chaining would be.  I was thinking of using StringBuilder() and defining each 'piece' of the  form as a static String.  When the  completedForm was built it would be a concatination of the static and dynamic parts.  For example:

Comment: Cut myself off before I  could type  the example.

Comment: For some reason I can't type in the example.  One more try.

Answer (score 3):

It may be the most efficient for you to do it that way.  Unless you know this is a performance problem I wouldn't try guessing that it might be and put in something more complicated which might not make much difference in the end.

If you want your code to be faster, I suggest you profile it first with a profiler and work on the things it suggests you are spending the most time on.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not a particularly efficient way of doing things.

Whether it's worth investing time into improving on it depends on what else your program does, whether this is currently taking a large percentage of the processing time of the program.

If it is, you could consider [**a trie**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) with what you want to replace and have the nodes contain what you want to replace it with. Then you'd need to iterate through the string and do lookups in the trie as you go, building up the resulting string with a `StringBuilder` or just regular strings using concatenation.

With either method, to prevent excessive amounts of code, (since I see all replacements you mentioned is replacing a string with a variable with the same name, not sure if this is a rule of just an example) my first thought is [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/), although it's not really advised for production-level code if it can be avoided, or simply a map instead of the variables.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem that bad to me, performance-wise.  If the operation of creating a new String were *very* expensive relative to other kinds of operations, I could think of other ways to solve the problem, such as searching for all the placeholder names first and creating an array that tags the characters in the template that will need to be replaced, and then using StringBuilder to piece everything together.  But I doubt that allocating a new String is that much more expensive (although I haven't tried it), and I suspect (like Peter) that adding a complicated solution won't make much difference and could make things worse.

With your approach, I'd be more concerned about correctness.  Are you absolutely, 100%, sure that none of the replacement strings in an earlier `replaceFirst()` can possibly match a "placeholder" key in a later `replaceFirst()`?  If this "form" is something that uses data from a web page, that's the general sort of problem that a tricky attacker could take advantage of, by saying their name is "account_number" or something like that.

EDIT: One more thing: `replaceFirst()` treats $ and \ specially in the second argument.  If there is any chance that one of the replacement strings could contain one of those characters, you'll need to deal with it (see [Matcher.quoteReplacement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement%28java.lang.String%29)).